# Sufficient conditions for a general linear process to be well-defined

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes

I'm reading a textbook stating that for a general linear process $Y_t = e_t +\sum_{i\geq 1}\phi_i e_{t-i}$, it suffices to assume that $\sum_{i\geq 1}\phi^2_i<\infty$. Why is that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Square summability ensures that the linear process generates a mean square convergent random variable, see e.g. Appendix 3A in Hamilton, Time Series Analysis.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Thanks for your help. From what I could get of Hamilton, the square summability is to ensure the ergodicity(for the mean) assumption, i.e., something like asymptotic stationarity.  But there is a difference. In Hamilton, this square summability condition is applied to the autocovariance terms $\gamma_k $, not to the terms in $Cov(Y_t,Y_{t-k})=\sum \phi_{i}\phi_{k+i}Var(e_{t-k-i})=\sum \phi_{i}\phi_{k+i} \sigma^2_e$

Comment: @ChristophHanck I've just found the justification for your assertion in the Brockwell intro to time series. They also say that it ensures that $Y_t$ also converges with  probability one (a.s.), by implying $E|Y_t|<\infty$. Could you shed some light on this?

Comment: @ChristophHanck I'm sorry, you were right. I've just found below the section you were referring to in the appendix of Hamilton's book. Thanks ;)